# PHP Create Sub Arrays from Master Array based on keys

Tags: php, arrays, loops, subset

This pertains to PHP.
I have an array of arrays that is a recordset from a db query:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Amazon
            [1] => AmazonSendTracking
            [2] => 
            [3] => 1
            [4] => IN
            [5] => 2020-01-07 11:32:18
            [6] => 7
            [7] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Amazon
            [1] => AmazonGetOrdersAndMove
            [2] => 
            [3] => 4
            [4] => ALL
            [5] => 2020-01-07 11:32:18
            [6] => 6
            [7] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test
            [1] => RedirectTest1
            [2] => data=data1&data2=data2&testvar=testvariable
            [3] => 4
            [4] => ALL
            [5] => 2020-01-07 11:32:18
            [6] => 19
            [7] => 17
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test
            [1] => RedirectTest2
            [2] => data=value&data2=value2&testvar=value3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => ALL
            [5] => 2020-01-07 11:32:18
            [6] => 19
            [7] => 25
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Amazon
            [1] => AmazonPushInventory
            [2] => 
            [3] => 15
            [4] => ALL
            [5] => 2020-01-07 11:32:18
            [6] => 27
            [7] => 26
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Amazon
            [1] => CalculateFloorCeiling
            [2] => 
            [3] => 15
            [4] => ALL
            [5] => 2020-01-07 11:32:18
            [6] => 27
            [7] => 27
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Amazon
            [1] => AmazonSubmitPricingXML
            [2] => 
            [3] => 15
            [4] => ALL
            [5] => 2020-01-07 11:32:18
            [6] => 27
            [7] => 28
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Amazon
            [1] => AmazonSubmitPricingXMLResetBusinessAndFlipEm
            [2] => 
            [3] => 1440
            [4] => OUT
            [5] => 
            [6] => 8
            [7] => 6
        )

)
```

the Value in the 7th position (6) of the sub-array represents a "group" that I want to break out into individual arrays.

So I want the above to become one array of items not in any group and then a new array for each group like this:

**Array1 - All Items not in a group**

```
Array1
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Amazon
            [1] => AmazonSendTracking
            [2] => 
            [3] => 1
            [4] => IN
            [5] => 2020-01-07 11:32:18
            [6] => 7
            [7] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Amazon
            [1] => AmazonGetOrdersAndMove
            [2] => 
            [3] => 4
            [4] => ALL
            [5] => 2020-01-07 11:32:18
            [6] => 6
            [7] => 4
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Amazon
            [1] => AmazonSubmitPricingXMLResetBusinessAndFlipEm
            [2] => 
            [3] => 1440
            [4] => OUT
            [5] => 
            [6] => 8
            [7] => 6
        )
)
```

**Array2 - 1st group**

```
Array2(
 [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test
            [1] => RedirectTest1
            [2] => data=data1&data2=data2&testvar=testvariable
            [3] => 4
            [4] => ALL
            [5] => 2020-01-07 11:32:18
            [6] => 19
            [7] => 17
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test
            [1] => RedirectTest2
            [2] => data=value&data2=value2&testvar=value3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => ALL
            [5] => 2020-01-07 11:32:18
            [6] => 19
            [7] => 25
        )
)
```

**Array3 - 2nd group**

```
Array3(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Amazon
            [1] => AmazonPushInventory
            [2] => 
            [3] => 15
            [4] => ALL
            [5] => 2020-01-07 11:32:18
            [6] => 27
            [7] => 26
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Amazon
            [1] => CalculateFloorCeiling
            [2] => 
            [3] => 15
            [4] => ALL
            [5] => 2020-01-07 11:32:18
            [6] => 27
            [7] => 27
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Amazon
            [1] => AmazonSubmitPricingXML
            [2] => 
            [3] => 15
            [4] => ALL
            [5] => 2020-01-07 11:32:18
            [6] => 27
            [7] => 28
        )
)
```

Im just not sure what array functions would be best used to accomplish this. I have tried getting the count of each group using the following.
I have a loop that steps through the master array (array of arrays call $rs) and while in the loop I pull out the 7th position into a variable called $HeaderRecNbr and then do this:

```
$GroupCount=array_count_values(array_column($rs, 6))[$HeaderRecNbr];
```

but Im not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Is it always in the 7th position? And are you looking the `array_count_values()` function to return an array of arrays, which hold the arrays organized by the group value (in index 6)?

Comment: The value is position 7 (6 in array zero based counting) will always represent the ID of the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an array indexed by the group from index 6.  This will create a sub-array for each group indexed by the group number:

```
foreach($array as $v) {
    $groups[$v[6]][] = $v;
}
```

Then to get the items that are alone in a group, check if there is exactly one sub-array and add it to another array.  Then remove it from the group array:

```
foreach($groups as $k => $v) {
    if(count($v) == 1) {
        $other[] = $v;  // or $other[$v[0][6]][] = $v;
        unset($groups[$k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly!  Note there is a typo in your unset, the array is named $groups not $group.   Thank you!

Comment: Now that I have an array $groups with an index based on the group id (pos 6) how could I arrange the $other array so it also had an index based on the group id?

Comment: Just do the same thing `$other[$v[6]][] = $v;` edited with a comment

Comment: Im getting Undefined offset: 6 now.

Comment: I figured it out...it should be ```$other[$v[0][6]] = $v; ```
Thank you so much! you totally rock!

Comment: Sorry I didn't test was just visualizing the array in my head.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $mainArray = ... all rows variable here..
$groupedArray = [];
$countArray = [];
foreach ($mainArray as $k => $v) {
    $groupedArray[$v[6]][] = $v;
    $countArray[$v[6]]++;
}
$singleItems = [];
$multipleItems = [];
foreach ($groupedArray as $k => $v) {
    if ($countArray[$k] > 1) $multipleItems[] = $v;
    else $singleItems = $v;
}

... do something with single and multi - groups...
```

1: start by grouping all items in groups by the 6th item of sub array... keep count of them at same time
2. Separate single and multiple items groups in 2 arrays... 
3. Do whatever you need with multi-items groups.

Answer (score 0):

This function will group them by desired index, then combine the ones that dont have any other with same index, and return an array of arrays, ungrouped, then all grouped.

```
function sortByIndex( $data, $index ) {
    $sortedData = array();
    $ungroupedData = array();
    // Make sure you can loop through
    if ( ! is_array( $data ) ) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    foreach ( $data as $key => $arrayToInspect ) {
        if ( ! isset( $sortedData[$arrayToInspect[$index]] ) ) {
            $sortedData[$arrayToInspect[$index]] = array();
        }
        $sortedData[$arrayToInspect[$index]][] = $arrayToInspect;
    }

    // Combine as desired
    foreach ( $sortedData as $groupId => $data ) {
        if ( count( $data ) < 2 ) {
            $ungroupedData[] = $data;
            unset( $sortedData[$groupId] );
        }
    }
    return ( array_merge( [ $ungroupedData ], array_values( $sortedData ) ) );
}
```